# How to fix MongoDB Fatal Assertion 28595 error?

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, containers, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to get mongo server up and running in a docker container but getting error:

```
2020-07-29T21:15:58.518-0500 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2020-07-29T21:15:58.621-0500 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-07-29T21:15:58.681-0500 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-07-29T21:15:58.684-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=747 port=27017 dbpath=/app/database 64-bit host=610312a6720b
2020-07-29T21:15:58.686-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.8
2020-07-29T21:15:58.687-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 43d25964249164d76d5e04dd6cf38f6111e21f5f
2020-07-29T21:15:58.689-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2020-07-29T21:15:58.690-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-07-29T21:15:58.692-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-07-29T21:15:58.693-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-07-29T21:15:58.694-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2020-07-29T21:15:58.696-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-07-29T21:15:58.697-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-07-29T21:15:58.698-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/app/database", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/app/database/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2020-07-29T21:15:58.711-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /app/database created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2020-07-29T21:15:58.715-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=483M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2020-07-29T21:15:59.442-0500 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1596075359:442302][747:0x7faa34ed4b00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /app/database/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1596075359:442302][747:0x7faa34ed4b00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /app/database/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2020-07-29T21:15:59.475-0500 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1596075359:475036][747:0x7faa34ed4b00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /app/database/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1596075359:475036][747:0x7faa34ed4b00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /app/database/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2020-07-29T21:15:59.504-0500 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1596075359:504949][747:0x7faa34ed4b00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /app/database/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1596075359:504949][747:0x7faa34ed4b00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /app/database/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2020-07-29T21:15:59.533-0500 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1596075359:533624][747:0x7faa34ed4b00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /app/database/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1596075359:533624][747:0x7faa34ed4b00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /app/database/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2020-07-29T21:15:59.538-0500 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2020-07-29T21:15:59.539-0500 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 1: Operation not permitted
2020-07-29T21:15:59.540-0500 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 915
2020-07-29T21:15:59.540-0500 F  -        [initandlisten]
```

Running the following command starts the server fine and is accessible outside docker container:

```
mongod --dbpath /app/database
```

but when following command is ran Mongo logs the above mentioned error log into the log file

```
service mongodb start
or
sudo service mongodb start
```

Not sure why this issue is causing. Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: You were running mongod as different users and now your current user cannot access the data files. Follow published documentation to start mongod properly.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by that. I'm trying to start mongod with dbpath as /app/database in both cases. Why does it run in one case while it doesn't run in another case?

Comment: /app/database is an linux internal directory which is bind using mount via docker.

Comment: Which documentation are you following?

Comment: I've designed an architecture that I would like to achieve. Of which saving database on local disk using bind mount is one of the aspects. My source of documentation is scattered. I'm not referring to any one documentation to be specific. In fact I've not found this architecture being used by others at all.

Comment: You took a bunch of pieces, assembled them and they are not working. So now you need to go through documentation for each of them and figure out how to use them properly. Are you able to write to your bind mounts from your container at all? If not get this fixed first by referring to docker documentation.

Comment: Yes I'm able to write to the location from the docker container and I've checked this already. Tried to search this in the documentation but I failed to find any relavent information.